# Core Data error - Swift

Tags: core-data, swift

I'd like to use this line of code, but xcode says: `Type 'ViewController' does not conform protocol 'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'`

Code:

```
fetchedResultController.delegate = self
```

Does someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

your class of Type 'ViewController' needs to conform to the protocol 'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'

**a protocol is an interface and you need to implement the methods it defines**

---

(and maybe [and I mean this in the least offensive way] read a book / a tutorial / attend a course to learn OOP and swift and cocoa touch)